# RDLC reports not being centered

Tags: asp.net, rdlc

This is the screenshot of an RDLC report in my Visual Studio report designer

[image]

As you can see from the screenshot, my table is totally centered.

This is the screenshot of my report in running mode.

[image]

You can see that the table has moved to the right a bit.

I do not know why this is happening. I have set the CanGrow and CanShrink attribute of my individual columns to false, but I think my table body is growing.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like email address length is the reason - it causes this column to expand. You can test this theory by removing record #4 from you report's data source.

Check that two things are set in properties:

- click on containing Text Box and click F4. Make sure that "Can Grow" property is set to true (which most likely already is)
- right click on containing Text Box and go to TextBox property window. Make sure that sizing option "Allow Height to increase" is checked ON (in General tab). This should push text in the column to wrap instead.

Do the same thing for all the columns that you anticipate longer text (like applicant name). Also, consider increasing initial width of this kind of columns to get more predictable formatting results.

Another thing to do is to remove all white space on the right and left of the table and setting all the margins to make page to be exactly 8.5 x 11 in total (if, for example, you are aiming to use letter page size). This would remove any "space to grow" for the table.